# How do you dynamically load different page objects in nightwatch based on the test environment?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I want to add a test for my app which involves taking payment. In my apps local environment it uses a stubbed payment page where you only need to click a button to fail or authorise the payment, in all other environments it shows a form where card details need to be filled in.

I currently have the test setup to check whether or not we need to use the real or stubbed payment in each command.

```
function isRealPayment(page) {
  return !page.api.globals.stubbedPayment;
}

module.exports = {
  commands: {
    verifyLoaded: function() {
      if (isRealPayment(this)) {
        return this.waitForElementVisible('@orderSummaryContainer');
      }
      return this.waitForElementVisible('@stubbedAuthorisedForm');
    },

    fillInPaymentDetails: function() {
      if (isRealPayment(this)) {
        this
          .setValue('@cardNumber', '4444333322221111')
          .setValue('@name', 'John Doe')
          .setValue('@expiryMonth', '12')
          .setValue('@expiryYear', '25')
          .setValue('@securityCode', '123');
      }
    },

    submitPayment: function() {
      if (isRealPayment(this)) {
        return this.click('@submitButton');
      }
      return this.click('@stubbedSubmitButton');
    }
  },

  elements: {
    orderSummaryContainer: '#orderSummaryDetailsTop',
    cardNumber: '#cardNumber',
    name: '#cardholderName',
    expiryMonth: '#expiryMonth',
    expiryYear: '#expiryYear',
    securityCode: '#securityCode',
    submitButton: '#submitButton',

    stubbedAuthorisedForm: '.frm-AUTHORISED',
    stubbedSubmitButton: '.frm-AUTHORISED > input[type="submit"]'
  }
};
```

I would prefer it if I were able to define two different page objects, and choose which one to export based on the `stubbedPayment` global.
e.g

```
let realPaymentPage = {
  commands: {
    verifyLoaded: function() {
      return this.waitForElementVisible('@orderSummaryContainer');
    },

    fillInPaymentDetails: function() {
      this
        .setValue('@cardNumber', '4444333322221111')
        .setValue('@name', 'John Doe')
        .setValue('@expiryMonth', '12')
        .setValue('@expiryYear', '25')
        .setValue('@securityCode', '123');
    },

    submitPayment: function() {
      return this.click('@submitButton');
    }
  },

  elements: {
    orderSummaryContainer: '#orderSummaryDetailsTop',
    cardNumber: '#cardNumber',
    name: '#cardholderName',
    expiryMonth: '#expiryMonth',
    expiryYear: '#expiryYear',
    securityCode: '#securityCode',
    submitButton: '#submitButton'
  }
};

let stubbedPaymentPage = {
  commands: {
    verifyLoaded: function() {
      return this.waitForElementVisible('@authorisedForm');
    },

    fillInPaymentDetails: function() {
      // Do nothing
    },

    submitPayment: function() {
      return this.click('@submitButton');
    }
  },

  elements: {
    authorisedForm: '.frm-AUTHORISED',
    submitButton: '.frm-AUTHORISED > input[type="submit"]'
  }
};

if (browser.globals.stubbedPayment) {
  module.exports = stubbedPaymentPage;
} else {
  module.exports = realPaymentPage;
}
```

But I can't find a way to access the global variables when not in a page command. Is this possible? Or is there another way to load a different page object based on the test environment?

Answer (score 2):

**Sure you are. example solution:**

Firstly lets create `Global.js` file.

Add path to the file inside nightwatch.json:

```
"globals_path": "Global.js"
```

In Global.js define before method (it is executed once before any of test):

```
var self = module.exports = {
    environment: undefined,
    before: function (done) {
       // parseArgumentsAndGetEnv is function you need to implement on your own to find your env param
        self.environment = parseArgumentsAndGetEnv(process.argv);
        console.log("Run against: " + self.environment);

        done();
    }
};
```

Now in tests you can use this variable:

```
if (browser.globals.environment == 'Test') {
   // do something
} else if (browser.globals.environment == 'Prod') {
  // do something else
}
```